# vault -autocomplete-install fails to find any shells

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When run within a Docker container, `vault -autocomplete-install` fails.

```sh
$ docker run --privileged -ti vault:latest -autocomplete-install
Error executing CLI: Did not find any shells to install
```

I tried to run with `strace vault...` but nothing stands out. I also tried to look into [the source](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/vendor/github.com/posener/complete/cmd/install/install.go) but all seems fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It misses the `USER` environment variable and cannot find the home directory when [scanning for .bashrc etc. files](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/vendor/github.com/posener/complete/cmd/install/install.go#L61). The problem can be reproduced outside of docker with

```sh
$ ( unset USER ; vault -autocomplete-install )
Error executing CLI: Did not find any shells to install
```

and similarly fixed in docker with

```sh
export USER=root
```

Comment: You should accept your answer as the solution: 'export USER=root' worked well for me too.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, in Dockerfile:

`RUN touch $HOME/.bashrc \
  && vault -autocomplete-install`

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue on window machine and to resolve issue i followed below steps on CLI ( Git bash)

1) cd ~                {Home directory}

2) touch .bashrc       {Created .bashrc file}

3) rerun the command "vault -autocomplete-install" and worked without any issue

Above solution worked for me